# Appropriate design pattern for coupled Objects

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, architectural-patterns, patterns-and-practices

I code an Object-Oriented simulation where you can have a `Unit` move on a `Terrain`. The cost of such move depends both on both `Unit` capabilities and `Terrain` features: a boat can move on water, a plane can move everywhere, a car cannot run on terrain, etc.

Current implementation uses a table, but this grows complex (as terrain can also have features like roads, rails, rivers, etc.).

Are there adapted software patterns to handle such coupled objects ?

*Update:*

For practical purposes, consider the example of a wargame at a tactical scale, extending from antiquity to modern time. Map is divided in squares of hexagons of terrain.

Units can be infantry of various experience, cavalry, transport vehicles, armored vehicles like tanks, helicopters, etc. The number of units should reach at best ~50.

Terrain can be plain, desert, forest (of various density), water, marsh. On top, terrain can be modified and that can create impact on movement: it can be on fire, contain mines, be flooded, etc. such situation have their own impact on Unit movement as well.

When a Unit moves from one location to the other, the cost of said move should be provided. This cost represents the time and/or energy to reach this new location, and depends on the Unit type and the Terrain type, including terrain modifiers.

My objective is to keep the code easy (or at least not too confusing) to read and maintain, despite the potential number of rules and modifiers.

I originally started a `unit.getMoveCost(terrain)` method but this depends on a lot of `terrain` properties. But of course implementing a `terrain.getMoveCost(unit)` has the same issues. And in both cases, adding a new terrain and/or unit forces to review both `Terrain` and `Unit`.

Comment: I don't think I can provide a detailed answer. But have you considered the mediator pattern? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern

Comment: What you are looking for is a layer/abstraction for indirection between Terrains and Units. So, have you considered modeling `move` as an object? You coule solve concrete rules of movements from a hierarchy of `Movements`

Comment: A cost matrix isn't the worst approach, especially when the costs for certain unit/terrain combinations are mostly arbitrary. But if there are some standard rules which allow to derive the costs for, lets say 90% of all cases, and only 10% have to be dealt with in some special manner, you may want to implement something like **double dispatch**. I recommend to search this site for this keyword, there are several questions about it.

Comment: Before you worry about code, you need to figure out how you will compute these costs manually, and what the rules are, exactly. If you can't create an exact specification to do it by hand you will certainly have problems doing it in code, and writing test cases (which rely on you independently knowing the expected behavior) will be problematic as well. How *exactly* do you plan to compute these things?

Answer (score 3):

There are only three 'patterns' here.

1. Units know about Terrain
2. Terrain knows about Units
3. Something else knows about both of them

When the number of kinds of Units and Terrain can both grow arbitrarily 3 becomes very attractive. Also, if you can push 3 out of the type system as some kind of configuration it avoids the need to simulate double dispatch. Few languages support that natively.

Personally I've had great success resolving this issue with hash tables. You can nest hash tables and look up any number of keys to find a value that could be a number, a method, or an object.

It might not feel really OOP but I've learned over the years to stop asking the type system to do things it's not good at. Sure you can hack around that and force it to simulate features it doesn't really have but that rarely creates code that is fun to look at.

Now if you're willing to completely refocus the design there is also a rules based approach. [Eric Lippert's](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/6505/eric-lippert) [Wizards and Warriors](https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/) post remains my favorite treatment of this. If it seems like a hard slog getting to the solution in part 5 just imagine trying to get that far with just your own code. This is a nasty rabbit hole to get lost in.

So unless you can think of a good reason not to, my vote goes to 3. Just come up with a nice simple way to populate whatever that "something else" thing is.

Answer (score 1):

You need to **reduce the coupled objects to abstractions**, then allow the abstractions to interact. This will reduce the number of possible combinations and simplify the problem considerably. Also, it's kind of fun to do. Deciding on those abstractions is the creative part of this project.

Here's some abstractions that come to mind as an example. You might have a `IMobileUnit` interface that exposes some properties:

```
enum TreadStyle { RacingTires, SnowTires, AllTerrainTires, Caterpillar, Skids }

interface IMobileUnit
{
    bool CanFloat { get; }
    float Height { get; }
    float HorsePower { get; }
    float Length { get; }
    TreadStyle TreadStyle { get; }
    float Weight { get; }
}
```

You'd then implement as part of each general type of unit...

```
class Tank : IMobileUnit
{
    public bool CanFloat => false; //lol
    public float Weight { get; protected set; } = default(float); //Depends on the type of Tank, should be set when constructing
    public TreadStyle TreadStyle => TreadStyle.Caterpillar; //All tanks use caterpillar treads 
    //etc.
}
```

And set them via constructor or factory

```
public class TankFactory
{
    public T MakeTank<T>(string modelNumber)
    {
        if (modelNumber == "Sherman") return new Tank
        {
            Weight = 2000,
            Length = 10,
            HorsePower = 50
        };

        if (modelNumber == "M1") return new Tank 
        {
            Weight = 3000, 
            Length = 10, 
            HorsePower = 150
        };
        throw ArgumentException("I don't know how to build that kind of tank.");
    }
}
```

I would suggest Terrain has a collection of TerrainFeatures which has its own interface:

```
class Terrain : List<ITerrainFeature>
{
}

interface ITerrainFeature
{
    bool RequiresCaterpillar { get; ] 
    bool RequiresFloatation { get; ]
    float MaxWeightAllowed { get; ]
}
```

and set them in classes that implement the interface:

```
class MuddyTerrain :  ITerrainFeature
{
    public bool RequiresCaterpiller => true;
    public bool RequiresFloatation => false;
}

class LakeTerrain : ITerrainFeature
{
    public bool RequiresFloatation => true;
}

public class LargeBridge : ITerrainFeature
{
    public float MaxWeightAllowed => 10000;
```

The interaction of these interfaces is contained in a special class of its own that represents the physics engine or game rules or whatever you want to call it.

```
class TerrainMovementRules
{
    float GetTravelDistance(List<ITerrainFeature> terrain, IMobileUnit unit)
    {
        if (terrain.Any( x => x.RequiresFloation ) && !unit.CanFloat) return 0;
        if (unit.Weight > terrain.Min( x => x.MaxWeightAllowed ) return 0;
        //etc...
    }
}
```

This way you avoid having to add specific code for each and every type of unit.  You just use an existing set of properties and populate them.

Comment: This would definitely help to logically group units based on their properties/interfaces and make the final rulesot manageable and logical, thanks.